# Windows 8 Javascript Promises

Tags: html, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have the following function:

```
function pickContacts() {
    var output = "";

    // Create the picker
    var picker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
    picker.commitButtonText = "Select";

    var emailsPromise = new WinJS.Promise(function () {

        // Open the picker for the user to select contacts
        picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().then(function (contacts) {
            if (contacts.length > 0) {
                // Get selected e-mails                
                contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
                    contact.emails.every(function (email) { output += email.value + ";"; });
                });
                return output;
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        });
    });

    return emailsPromise;
};
```

This gets me a list of e-mail addresses from selected contacts.  So next I want to use that; here's my code:

```
document.getElementById("findEmail").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var emailAdd = document.getElementById("email");
    pickContacts().done(function (emails) {
         emailDets.value = emails;
    });
});
```

But I'm not getting the return value from pickContacts (which I've determined is actually returned). I'm guessing that there's something wrong with the way I'm handling the returned promise, but I can't seem to debug it (trying to step into it just exits the function).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pass the completed callback as a parameter of your promise function and then call it with the results you want to pass.  Esseintially:

```
var emailsPromise = new WinJS.Promise(function () {

    // Open the picker for the user to select contacts
    picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().then(function (contacts) {
        if (contacts.length > 0) {
            // Get selected e-mails                
            contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
                contact.emails.every(function (email) { output += email.value + ";"; });
            });
            return output;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    });
});
```

becomes:

```
var emailsPromise = new WinJS.Promise(function (complete, error, progress) {

    // Open the picker for the user to select contacts
    picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().then(function (contacts) {
        if (contacts.length > 0) {
            // Get selected e-mails                
            contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
                contact.emails.every(function (email) { output += email.value + ";"; });
            });
            complete(output);
        } else {
            complete("");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a new promise--just return the promise from pickMultipleContactsAsync.then. The promises spec says that the return value from .then is another promise that's fulfilled when your completed handler finishes, and the fulfillment value is the return value of the completed handler. So you can just do this:

```
    return picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().then(function (contacts) {
        if (contacts.length > 0) {
            // Get selected e-mails                
            contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
                contact.emails.every(function (email) { output += email.value + ";"; });
            });
            return output;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    });
```

The other way works, but just creates yet another promise that isn't needed, and makes your code a little more complex.